# werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request:The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand. KeyError: 'video'

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, flask, httprequest, face-recognition

I'm trying to pass a live video stream from JS to python for face recognition using a HTTP request and I get the error
`werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand. KeyError: 'video'`

After checking my terminal for the logs of the app I see the data type of the stream coming in as `Bytes` and I believe I need to convert it to a numpy array before passing it to a python script.

My current implementation is as follows
I have my JS code on a html template that opens a `POST` request to my python file which now processes the live video stream to get the frames with faces in them.

Here's the HTML with the JS

```
`<button id="startBtn" onclick="openCam()">Open Webcam</button>
<br>
<!-- close button -->
<button id="closeButton" onclick="closeCam()">Close</button>
<br>
<!--video element to show the live video-->
<video id="video" autoplay></video>
<!-- javascript video stream -->
<script>
    const video = document.getElementById('video');
    const closeButton = document.getElementById('closeButton');

    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    
    let intervalID;

    function openCam(){
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
        .then((stream) => {
            video.srcObject = stream;
            intervalID = setInterval(() => {
            context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            const dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
            const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', '/markin');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            xhr.send(`video=${encodeURIComponent(dataURL)}`);
            }, 1000 / 30);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
    }

    // Close the live stream by removing the interval counter
    function closeCam(){
        // const stopButton = document.getElementById('stopButton');
        closeButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        clearInterval(intervalID);
        video.srcObject.getTracks()[0].stop();
        window.location.href = "{{ url_for('markin') }}";    
    });
    }
</script>`
```

Here's the python end of the code

```
`# get the video stream from the data request
data = request.form['video']
dataURL = request.form.get('video',False)
if dataURL is not null:
    print("DATA IS NOT EMPTY!!!")
    # print(dataURL)
    print(type(data))
    print(data)
else:
    print("DATA IS EMPTY!!!")
# Decode Base64-encoded video stream data
decoded_data = base64.b64decode(dataURL.split(',')[1])
img = decoded_data
if img is not null:
    print("IMAGE IS NOT EMPTY!!!")
    print(type(img))
    print(img)`
```

I've tried applying the other options for live video streaming such as WebRTC and it's quite an uphill journey trying to configure it to my app and would appreciate a more straight forward example on how to do so if you  provide it as a solution to this question.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that the key `video` could not be found in the form data of the request.

The following simple example is essentially based on your code.
The individual images are extracted from the video at an interval and sent to the server as files. Here the faces are recognized and marked with a rectangle. The images are then sent back to the client where they are displayed.

```py
from flask import Flask, abort, render_template, request, send_file
from io import BytesIO
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import os


face_classifier = cv.CascadeClassifier(
    os.path.join(
        cv.data.haarcascades, 
        'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'
    )
)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.post('/process')
def process():
    file = request.files.get('image')
    if file:
        nparr = np.fromstring(file.read(), np.uint8)
        frame = cv.imdecode(nparr, cv.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR)
        frame_gray = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        faces = face_classifier.detectMultiScale(frame_gray, 1.3, 5)
        for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
            frame = cv.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2) 

        _, buffer = cv.imencode('.jpg', frame)
        return send_file(
            BytesIO(buffer), 
            as_attachment=False, 
            mimetype='image/jpeg'
        )
    abort(400)
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Index</title>
        <style>
            main {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                align-items: center;
            }
            .controls {
                margin: .64rem 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <div class="controls">
                <button id="toggle-rec-btn">Start</button>
            </div>
            <img id="preview" width="400" height="300" />
        </main>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function(uri) {
                const FPS = 6;

                const createOffVideo = (width=400, height=300) => {
                    const video = document.createElement('video');
                    video.width = width;
                    video.height = height;
                    return video;
                };

                const createOffCanvas = (width=400, height=300) => {
                    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                    canvas.width = width;
                    canvas.height = height;
                    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                    return [canvas, context];
                };

                const offscreenVideo = createOffVideo();
                const preview = document.getElementById('preview');
                const toggleBtn = document.getElementById('toggle-rec-btn');
                
                let intervalID; 

                toggleBtn && toggleBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    if (offscreenVideo && !offscreenVideo.paused) { 
                        clearInterval(intervalID);
                        offscreenVideo.pause();
                        offscreenVideo.srcObject.getTracks().forEach(track => {
                            track.stop();
                        });
                        toggleBtn.innerText = 'Start';
                    } else {
                        if (!(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia)) {
                            console.error('getUserMedia not supported.')
                            return;
                        }
                
                        const [canvas, context] = createOffCanvas();
                        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
                            .then(stream => {
                                offscreenVideo.srcObject = stream;
                                offscreenVideo.play();

                                intervalID = setInterval(
                                    () => {
                                        context.drawImage(
                                            offscreenVideo, 
                                            0, 0, 
                                            canvas.width, canvas.height
                                        );
                                        canvas.toBlob(
                                            blob => {
                                                const formData = new FormData();
                                                formData.append('image', blob);
                                                fetch(uri, {
                                                    method: 'post', 
                                                    cache: 'no-cache',
                                                    body: formData
                                                })
                                                    .then(resp => resp.ok && resp.blob())
                                                    .then(blob => {
                                                        const objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                                                        preview.src = objectURL;
                                                    });
                                            }, 
                                            'image/jpeg', 
                                            0.95
                                        );
                                    }, 
                                    1000/FPS
                                );
                                toggleBtn.innerText = 'Stop';
                            });
                    }
                });

            })({{ url_for('process') | tojson }});
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```